# How to start an express server on gcloud but not at the root of the domain?

Tags: express, dns, gcloud

I explain my problem,
I have a Gcloud domain "example.appspot.com" (for example) with a website from squareSpace. I would like to add a web application in node.js on this domain without overwriting the original site.
I would like to connect  the user at the web app on this link "example.appspot.com/webApp/". And if you go at "example.appspot.com" you are on the squareSpace website.

If I deploy the web application and go to "example.appspot.com", I have the web application, but the website from squareSpace is down ...
Yet my application has no "get or post" for "/", the first page is "/login".
If I go on "/" I just have "Cannot GET /"

I tried to use dispath.yaml but it don't work.

```
dispatch:
  - url: "example.appspot.com/webApp"
    service: default
```

Nothing change and "example.appspot.com/webApp" not work...

And i tried to use openapi-appengine.yaml.

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "WebApp"
  title: "Title WebApp"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "example.appspot.com/webApp"
```

But it don't want the "/" in host.

I tried to use a handlers in app.yaml but it not work...

I don't find solution.

Do you have any idea how I can tell gcloud to use the application only on "/ webApp/" ?
I'm sorry for my bad english level, i improve it every day.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this, depending on your scenario:

1) Express routes:

each route executes the logic you need. Node works with a module.exports/require system, so for each route you can have a different JS file that exports all due functions, used in the route's code.

Example:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const index = require('./index');
  res.send(index.hello());
});

app.get('/webapp', (req, res) => {
    const webapp = require('./webapp');
    res.send(webapp.appFunction());
  });
```

**index.js**

```
exports.hello = function() {
    return "Hello";
  }
```

**webapp.js**

```
exports.appFunction = function() {
    return "App Function";
  }
```

2) Service redirect: If you need a full app working at some endpoint and not some functions, then you can  deploy the webapp as a distinct service within the same application, and redirect the client request to this service at a given endpoint.

For this, create and deploy your webapp service exactly as the default app from its own folder, with a dedicated `package.json` and `app.yaml`. Just **specify the service name** in `app.yaml`: `service: webapp`

Once deployed, your service will be available at a weblink in the form `https://[SERVICE_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com`, which you can use to redirect from your default application's endpoint:

```
app.get('/webapp', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('https://[SERVICE_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com');
  });
```

[More info about services and routing here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-requests-are-routed). You can also [manage routing with dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/dispatch-yaml):

Example if your service ID is "webapp"

```
dispatch:
  - url: "example.appspot.com/webApp"
    service: webapp
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer alp.
For now i'm working on something else, but i think it's the good method for my problem.
I will try this later. For now we use an another domain for the beta.
But we go into PROD in a month and i will need to do this.

Comment: no worries, you will manage it, the service approach (rather than routes) might be the best in your situation. Let me know when you got this tested.